# Generic class repository with parameter for sorting

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic repository like this:

```
public class EntityMethods1<TModel> where TModel : class
{

    public static List<TModel> GetAll()
    {
        using (DataContext context = new DataContext())
        {
            var propertyInfo = typeof(TModel).GetProperty("");
            return context.Set<TModel>().OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

And then I can inherit like this to access the methods.

```
public class DBTABLENAME : Generic<DBTABLENAME>
{
}
```

I've been searching the entire day how to pass a parameter to the generic repository from the Entity that inherits from him, tried with constructors on both and still no luck, it seems like the constructor won't execute and I get a null.

I want to inherit like this:

```
public class DBTABLENAME : Generic<DBTABLENAME>("defaultSortField")
{
}
```

I'm not good at generics and still trying to learn. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Instead of passing property name you can pass the expression to be used in order by clause. `Func<TModel, TKey> orderBy`

Comment: Remember that anything you put in an EF query must be translatable to T-SQL by the EF expression evaluator. What you want to do is accept an appropriately typed expression into your query as a parameter. Take a look at *Predicate Builder* and more generally, *LinqKit*

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Probably instead of passing a default order string I can pass a default Function. And with EF expressions, using propertyInfo I can achieve that but I have to hard code the string, I wanted to pass a parameter.   I'll will try passing a Function. Thank you all.